# How to solve HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure when I use Topshelf to create windows service under asp.netcore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, topshelf

I create a asp.netcore project with visual studio 2017. And I install TopShelf from Nuget and add code in Program.Main() below:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var rc = HostFactory.Run(x =>                                   
     {
         x.Service<MainService>(s =>                                   
         {
             s.ConstructUsing(name => new MainService(args));                
             s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());                         
             s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());                          
         });
         x.RunAsLocalSystem();                                       

         x.SetDescription("ASP.NETCoreTest");                   
         x.SetDisplayName("ASP.NETCoreTest");                                  
         x.SetServiceName("ASP.NETCoreTest");                                  
     });                                                             

     var exitCode = (int)Convert.ChangeType(rc, rc.GetTypeCode());  
     Environment.ExitCode = exitCode;
 }
```

In MainService.cs:

```
public void Start()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.StartExecuting(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
public void StartExecuting()
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Stratup.cs is default.

Next, I run IIS Express, and it can work, showing as (although it is a little strange)(https://localhost:44345/):

[image]

Next, I add RuntimeIdentifiers win7-x64 in PropertyGroup and publish application in CMD:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win7-x64
```

Finally, I install ASP.NETCoreTest.exe and start ASP.NETCoreTest.exe, But it show as (https://localhost:44345/):
[image]

In Event Management, it tell me the error:
[image]

What should I do?
Please help me, thanks!

Update: If I exit IIS Express, it show it cannot connect to this site.
Maybe site should be opened with other way (Not https://localhost:44345/)?

Comment: I have faced with this issue back then, there is no clue what part of the project produces the error. to get an exact error just simply run your project.exe file to see the output.

Comment: I run ASP.NETCoreTest.exe and it show application started. But no site appear.

Comment: Why are you trying to use IIS Express? Using TopShelf gives you a windows service.

Comment: @ColinM Thanks, I already exit IIS Express, but I run https://localhost:44345/, it show it cannot connect to this site.

Comment: @RickyChen that should run on http://localhost:5000

Comment: You're replying to the wrong person

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad WOW, Nice, It is work! But Why it should run on localhost:5000? And what is port in SSL?

Comment: @ColinM Sorry! But still thanks you reply to me!

Comment: @RickyChen it is kestrel, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @PayamKhaninejad OK, thanks, I will read it.